# Using sso for asp.net projects without external registration

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I have two asp.net projects at the different domains. These projects use one database.
Let say www.test1.com and www.test2.com. (Late will be more projects)

I already have registration form and registered users.

Now I need to implement SSO possibility without registration at the external sites (google, openId, facebook).

All implementation which I have found required external registration (CAS, Federation, Facebook, openId).

Also I have read this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossDomainSSOExample.aspx, but as far as I understood from comments such solution very insecure.

Please suggest solution or existed library which can help me to use SSO without external registration.

Comment: In any single sign-on environment some entity has to act as the trusted authority. If you're just wanting to share user accounts between two sites then true SSO might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the exact same solution for a client I was working for, I did the research and the only good solutions that I found where either too complex and not well documented or too expensive (I forgot which companies I looked into). So I decided to build a custom solution. 
This is a short summary of the solution implemented:
In order to make things more clear let's call "nodes" the domains where you wanted to authenticate a user, and "SSO" the provider of the authentication.
I used a solution that is similar to the one in the link you posted HOWEVER I used the Asp.Net security cookie whenever I wanted to authenticate a node, and also to authenticate the SSO website:

```
HttpCookie formsCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, false, HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(formsCookie);
```

This also allowed me to not have to query back the SSO provider for each web request as the example you posted seem to do.
I used a new AuthenticationKey for each time I wanted to communicate from the SSO provider back to the node that the authentication was successfull. 
Also I added some security features like encrypted communication and that the key could only be valid a max of 2 seconds (the time for the SSO to pass it to the node) and as soon as it was used it would be deleted.
I believe this solution is safe enough, however using an external ready made solution is surely safer.

It took me only a few days to implement the whole solution, so it's not too long of a task. However I cannot share the project as I am not sure the client would agree.
I hope those suggestions might help you.

Let us know what you decide to do in the end.